# Stand-alone interactive cell for ipython notebook

Tags: python, matlab, user-interface, jupyter-notebook

I'm using ipython notebook as a former Matlab user.  One feature I miss is matlab's "command window" - a separate interactive window that is always visible, no matter what part of the script you're editing.

Currently, I make a new cell everywhere I want to try something, but I can't simultaneously view this "prototyping cell" and any given part of my script, which is quite annoying.

My question: **Is there a way to quickly switch between a development environment and any given part of the python script?**

Any solutions welcome - I've even entertained having two browser windows open on the same script...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%qtconsole` magic - it will start a qtconsole attached to the same kernel as your notebook.

Following https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2593/, you can have something like the following in your `.jupyter/custom/custom.js` and add a button to launch the qtconsole.

```
$([Jupyter.events]).on('notebook_loaded.Notebook', function(){
    // Create a custom button in toolbar that execute `%qtconsole` in kernel
    Jupyter.toolbar.add_buttons_group([
        {
             'label'   : 'Run QTconsole',
             'icon'    : 'fa fa-terminal', // select your icon from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons
             'callback': function () {
                 Jupyter.notebook.kernel.execute('%qtconsole')
             }
        }
        // add more button here if needed.
    ]);
});
```